# JSON.parse in Javascript disorder select

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, ajax

I receive from api a Json like this:

```
{
  "paises":{
    "145":"CHINA (53)",
    "150":"ESPAÑA (45)",
    "68":"HOLANDA (38)",
    "236":"RUMANIA (52)"
  }
}
```

List of countries always alwais is order alphabetic but when add to a select list show in disorder and order by id.Like this:

```
 "68":"HOLANDA (38)",
 "145":"CHINA (53)",
 "150":"ESPAÑA (45)",
 "236":"RUMANIA (52)"
```

This is a code:

```
   var datos = JSON.parse(data);

   $.each(datos.paises, function(id, valor) {
          $("#informe-id").append($('<option>', {
             value: id,
             text: valor,
          }));
   });
```

In my project I have this problem in more selects. In other list size is greater that 200, so that parse and short maybe it consumes a lot of resources. 
What is the best way to populate select keeping list in alphabetic order?

Thank a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Object.entries` to convert the object into array. Use `sort` to sort it.

Note: `orderedDatos` will be an array now and not an object. You might need to change something on your `$.each`

```js
var data = '{"paises": {"145": "CHINA (53)","150": "ESPAÑA (45)","68": "HOLANDA (38)","236": "RUMANIA (52)"}}';
var datos = JSON.parse(data);

var orderedDatos = Object.entries(datos.paises).sort((a, b) => a[1].localeCompare(b[1]));

$.each(orderedDatos, function(id, valor) {
  console.log(valor[0], valor[1]); //Use valor[0] to get the key | Use valor[1] to get the value
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Doc: [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: Hi! I get this error:  ```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.entries (<anonymous>)

Comment: On what line of code do you get this error? This is on browser and not on server like `node.js` Right? @pablogupi

Comment: In this line     ```var orderedDatos = Object.entries(datos.paises).sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0]);``` Error is in Chrome browser and this javascript run in CakePhp project.

Comment: Did you `JSON.parse` the `datos` variable?

Comment: Ok, with JSON.parse object is created, but not print in correct order. First country is Holanda and it should be China.

Comment: Isn't that what you are trying to do? You want to order by `id`, right? :) @pablogupi

Comment: No, I want order by name of country

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) it will return an array then you can use [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method array using [`String.localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) to get the required result.

**DEMO**

```js
var datos = {
  "paises": {
    "145": "CHINA (53)",
    "150": "ESPAÑA (45)",
    "68": "HOLANDA (38)",
    "236": "RUMANIA (52)"
  }
};

let paises = Object.entries(datos.paises).sort((a,b)=>a[1].localeCompare(b[1]));
$.each(paises, function(index, value) {
  $("#informe-id").append($('<option>', {
    value: value[0],
    text: value[1],
  }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="informe-id"></select>
```